# Executing a shell command in python's subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write the result of a shell-command in python to a file. The command is read from a variable. It works as long as I put the command directly into the python-command like here:

```
FIRST_OPEN=open(FIRST_TMP_FILE, 'w')
subprocess.call(["cat", "/etc/passwd"], stdout=FIRST_OPEN)
```

But as soon as I try to read the command from a variable, it's not working anymore:

```
FIRST_OPEN=open(FIRST_TMP_FILE, 'w')
FIRST_CMD='cat /etc/passwd'
subprocess.call([FIRST_CMD], stdout=FIRST_OPEN)
```

How do I have to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice both sources are not equivalent. Or you store the command as a list:

```
FIRST_OPEN=open(FIRST_TMP_FILE, 'w')
FIRST_CMD=['cat', '/etc/passwd']
subprocess.call(FIRST_CMD, stdout=FIRST_OPEN)
```

Or you split your command before using it:

```
FIRST_OPEN=open(FIRST_TMP_FILE, 'w')
FIRST_CMD='cat /etc/passwd'
subprocess.call(FIRST_CMD.split(), stdout=FIRST_OPEN)
```

Personally, I recommend you the first option.

Comment: Thank's the first example works great. I'm new to Python and the different brackets are a little bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `[FIRST_CMD]`, you are creating a list that looks like this: `["cat /etc/passwd"]`, not `["cat", "/etc/passwd"]`.  To change that, you *could* use `FIRST_CMD.split()` instead of `[FIRST_CMD]`.  You could also define `FIRST_CMD` as `["cat", "/etc/passwd"]`

Answer (score 0):

Try to define an array and then pass the array name without the brackets.

Your code will be

```
FIRST_OPEN=open(FIRST_TMP_FILE, 'w')
FIRST_CMD=['cat', '/etc/passwd']
subprocess.call(FIRST_CMD, stdout=FIRST_OPEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `shell=True` option in your subprocess call (check the docs under https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess).

Your example then:

```
FIRST_OPEN=open(FIRST_TMP_FILE, 'w')
FIRST_CMD='cat /etc/passwd'
subprocess.call([FIRST_CMD], stdout=FIRST_OPEN, shell=True)
```